# Python: fix import for symbolic link library

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools, setup.py

I have this structure in my project.

```
./lib_v1 ---> is a symboloic link for /libs/v1/lib
  package1/
    data.py
  main.py
  __init__.py


./lib_v2 ---> is a symboloic link for /libs/v2/lib
  package1/
    data1.py
    data2.py
  main.py
  __init__.py
```

I have a lib that has two versions v1 and v2 I would like to use both versions in another app. But I couldn't find a solution.
My main problem is with absolute import

In the main.py file in both versions of the libraries I have an absolute import

```
 from lib.package1 import data
```

When importing even one of the versions I get no module found because the v1 package is imported as lib_v1 and v2 package is imported as lib_v2.

I don't want to change all my import in the lib to relative import:

- Is it possible to change the package name when I build using setup.py (which will replace all absolute import with their respective package: `from lib.package1 import data --> from lib_v1.package1 import data` when I build for lib v1
- Is it possible to change all absolute import to relative import when building using setup.py
- Is there a solution where symbolic links can be used. For example import by telling python to consider lib as lib_v1 when importing v1/lib and lib as lib_v2 when importing v2/lib

Thank you very much.

Comment: Python packages are not built (in the sense of changes to the code), except they contain C code and that's not the problem here. You will have to adjust all references in code by hand or the help of an IDE with refactoring features.

Comment: I would like to automate the process so doing it by hand is not an option :'(

Comment: If I don't find the solution I think I will create a script that parses and change all the files in a package. However, I still think I can find an easy to implement solution.

Comment: Why not simply add `/libs/v1/lib` to sys.path, xor `/libs/v2/lib` if you want to switch?

Comment: Do you mean I can add /libs/v1/lib to sys.path import the v1 of the lib and then replaced it with /libs/v2/lib and import the v2 of the lib?